# Deployment of redundant libraries within multiple ears

Tags: performance, jakarta-ee, deployment, build, packaging

A Java EE application consists of different components in own ear files, each being quite large. This allows to disable or install only parts of the application. They contain redundant jar library files and also the war files share many library files in the lib folder.

Does this negatively impact the PemGen space and performance? Is there a better practice like using one ear file containing all shared libraries?

App server mainly used is Weblogic. Installation should work by just deploying files.

Answer (score 0):

One common practice is to place them in the (assuming tomcat)

```
$TOMCAT_HOME/common/lib
```

Or in any container place them in the classpath. I wouldn't go the way of the ear.

About the `PermGen` every ear, as an independent application, would have its own class loader. Depending on the configuration of you application (all the ears) one cannot access to the classes of the another. Since they are different applications.

So If you cannot place your shared libs where they are supposed to go I would ship every ear with the librarys.

Comment: The idea is to simplify deployment by including everything in the deployable packages without need for special actions depending on app server (weblogic is mainly used)

Comment: That's relevant to the question. You should add it as a requierement.